# Google News RSS Feed Android Development

Tags: android, http, rss, feed

I am trying to get news from the **google news rss feed** in my andorid application but I am not able to get the proper response. When I try the same using postman I am getting the response.

Code:

```
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");

        InputStream is;

        int status = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            is = connection.getErrorStream();

        }
        else {

            is = connection.getInputStream();

        }


        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            response.append(line);

            response.append('\r');
        }

        rd.close();

        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {


        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Resposne:

```
   <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>Not Found</H1><H2>Error 404</H2></BODY></HTML>
```

URL:

```
https://news.google.com/news/rss/story/dUuojVTpzSeUCKMyoBbnmsAFajvtM?ned=in&hl=en-IN&gl=IN
```

Response in Postman: [Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwHHH.png)

What need to be changed to get the response from the link?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your `targetURL` to contain what you expect it to contain using debugger

Comment: targetURL contains the url which is expected to get the response. I think i am making some mistake in the url parameters which i am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved easily using [RSS Parser Library](https://github.com/prof18/RSS-Parser). Just add the dependency in your gradle and then you can do something like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String urlString = "https://news.google.com/news/rss/story/dUuojVTpzSeUCKMyoBbnmsAFajvtM?ned=in&hl=en-IN&gl=IN";
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    parser.execute(urlString);
    parser.onFinish(new Parser.OnTaskCompleted() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(ArrayList<Article> list) {
            //what to do when the parsing is done
            //the Array List contains all article's data. For example you can use it for your adapter.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```